# How to I use a selectable field to change a sheet reference in a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula that looks something like this

```
=B2 - IF((B2 - Single!$D$1) < Single!$A$3, (B2 - Single!$A$2 - Single!$D$1) * Single!$B$2 + Single!$C$2, ...
```

I am using something of a lookup table on a sheet labeled "Single" for an analysis. I'd like to have a user selectable field (ideally something like a dropdown menu, say in cell S1) so I can switch between different sheets.

For example, if my sheet options were "Sheet1," "Sheet2," and "Sheet3," I would have a dropdown menu in cell S1 with those options and the formula would update to reflect the choice. If "Sheet1" were selected, it would be

```
B2 - IF((B2 - Sheet1!$D$1) < Sheet1!$A$3, (B2 - Sheet1!$A$2 - Sheet1!$D$1) * Sheet1!$B$2 + Sheet1!$C$2, ...
```

if "Sheet2" were selected, it would be

```
B2 - IF((B2 - Sheet2!$D$1) < Sheet2!$A$3, (B2 - Sheet2!$A$2 - Sheet2!$D$1) * Sheet2!$B$2 + Sheet2!$C$2, ...
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `INDIRECT` function to create your formulas, and a drop-down list so the user can choose the sheet.

Both are fairly easy to use:

(1) Drop-down list :

- Create a range with the values you want the user to be able to select; in your case this is a list with the worksheets. Let's assume they are meaningful enough for the user, so you can use the exact spelling in the list (but let's go with "Sheet1" etc. for this example).
- Choose the cell (assume A1) where you want to have the drop-down box, go to Data > "Data validation", List, and select the list of values (or range) that you created.

(2) Use now the `INDIRECT` function in your formula (for simplification, I just take a small part of the formula, but you have of course to use this wherever the formula uses Sheet1! in the formula)  :

instead of `B2 - Sheet1!$D$1` , you use `B2 - INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(A1;"!$D$1"))` .
(the `CONCATENATE` function takes the string "Sheet1" from cell A1, and combines this with the hard-coded text to give a valid cell reference, which is then evaluated with the `INDIRECT` function; instead of `CONCATENATE` you also can use the shorthand ampersand `&` operator; please also note that the function is renamed `CONCAT` as of Excel 2016, but `CONCATENATE` will still work in the foreseeable future to keep backward compatibility).